# JavaScript async/await policy, function resolves early / await doesn't wait

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have always been a little curious about an explanation about the concept.
I know I am just misunderstanding this.
Below are 2 functions, the first one meant to wait for the other one to finish before resolving with either true or false, but instead the second function resolves early with undefined.

```js
async function authorizeAccount() {
        if (await authHandler.onLogin()) {
                <!-- removed for brevity -->
        }
        else {
            alert("Something went wrong during authorization. Try again.")
        }
    }
    
    async onLogin() {
        try {
            const result = await authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig);
            if (result.authorizationCode) {
                axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/authorizespotify/' +        result.authorizationCode)
                    .then((result) => {
                        //Set token expiration date time
                        result.data.tokenExpirationDate = Date.now() + (result.data.expires_in * 1000);
                        asyncStorageHandler.storeObject('tokenObject', result);
                        return true;
                    })
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (error) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain WHY this function onLogin resolves immediately resulting in "undefined" being parsed by the if-statement?
And why the below earlier version of the same function DOES work? Apparently here we wait until the onLogin function resolves with either true/false before continuing in the authorizeAccount function.

```js
async onLogin() {
        try {
            const result = await authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig);
            if (result.accessToken) {
                await asyncStorageHandler.storeObject('tokenObject', result);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

I should probably mention that in the new version, all code is run, I get the tokens etc, and eventually return true, BUT the problem is that the promise is already resolved at that point. So how can I circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: The first snippet awaits for `authHandler.onLogin()` but there is no `authHandler` therefore the condition immediately evaluates to false. Did you mean to have `if (await this.onLogin())`, maybe?

Comment: Side note: Converting rejection/error to fulfillment/return with a flag is generally an antipattern. In most cases, the calling code should know that the attempt to check authorization *failed* rather than coming back with a negative result.

Comment: The second snippet is an old version, because to store a client secret server side, I have rewritten the function.

And yea, sorry, I have left out the fact that this is in a react native project using classes and components, so all is in order there. As mentioned, I do get the tokens and all  that, the function just resolves early.

Comment: `axios.get` is async. But you are not await it and not returning anything  from `onLogin` in your first snippet. You must do `return axios.get(...`

Comment: derpirscher. I see. But I would like to handle all my token logic in the same function before resolving. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain WHY this function onLogin resolves immediately resulting in "undefined"

Because you aren't using `await` or similar to wait for the promise from the `axios` call (more accurately, the one from your `then` handler) to finish. Nothing connects the promise from `axios.get().then()` to the promise `onLoad` creates implicitly, so the latter doesn't wait for the former to settle.

> And why the below earlier version of the same function DOES work?

Because it doesn't have that `axios` call, and *does* have `await` on what I assume is an asynchronous operation (given the name `asyncStorageHandler`). :-)

The absolute **minimum** change would be to add a `return` where I've marked `***` below, but you're also not waiting on the `asyncStorageHandler` promise, so I've flagged that as well:

```
// >>> I do NOT recommend mixing things this way, keep reading <<<
async function authorizeAccount() {
    if (await authHandler.onLogin()) {
            <!-- removed for brevity -->
    }
    else {
        alert("Something went wrong during authorization. Try again.")
    }
}

async onLogin() {
    try {
        const result = await authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig);
        if (result.authorizationCode) {
            return axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/authorizespotify/' +        result.authorizationCode)
// *** −−−−−^^^^^^
                .then((result) => {
                    //Set token expiration date time
                    result.data.tokenExpirationDate = Date.now() + (result.data.expires_in * 1000);
                    return asyncStorageHandler.storeObject('tokenObject', result);
// *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
                })
                .then(() => {    // *** Broke this out into its own
                    return true; // handler since we need to wait
                })               // for `asyncStorageHandler.storeObject`
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That makes the promise from the `async` function resolve to the promise from `axios.get().then()`, so ultimately what happens to the promise from `axios.get().then()` happens to the promise from the `async` function. Without that `return`, nothing connects the promise from the `async` function to the one from `axios.get().then()`.

But in general, it's best not to mix `await` and `.then` handlers (although there are occasional exceptions):

```
async function authorizeAccount() {
    if (await authHandler.onLogin()) {
            <!-- removed for brevity -->
    }
    else {
        alert("Something went wrong during authorization. Try again.")
    }
}

async onLogin() {
    try {
        const result = await authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig);
        if (result.authorizationCode) {
            const tokenResult = await axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/authorizespotify/' +        result.authorizationCode)
// −−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            tokenResult.data.tokenExpirationDate = Date.now() + (tokenResult.data.expires_in * 1000); // *** changed result to tokenResult
            await asyncStorageHandler.storeObject('tokenObject', tokenResult);                              // *** "
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or of course, don't use an `async` function at all and **only** use `.then` etc.:

```
onLogin() {
    return authorize(this.spotifyAuthConfig)
    .then(result => {
        if (result.authorizationCode) {
            return axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/authorizespotify/' + result.authorizationCode)
            .then(tokenResult => {
                tokenResult.data.tokenExpirationDate = Date.now() + (tokenResult.data.expires_in * 1000);
                return asyncStorageHandler.storeObject('tokenObject', tokenResult);
            })
            .then(() => {
                return true;
            });
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return false;
    });
}
```

...but the reason we have `async`/`await` is that using explicit handlers like that can get cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but am I correct when I say that the word await is just syntactic sugar for putting everything below in a .then() statement? I will rewrite it, but I do not think it is the root of the issue. (I did try rewriting it already, to be clear.)

Comment: @JoachimBülow - Yes and no. `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar for consuming promises, yes (but...the *good* kind of sugar). The problem with your code was that you weren't waiting for the promise to settle. The way I fixed it was to use `await` (since this was within an `async` function). The *other* way to fix it would be to use a `.then` handler **and** either `await` or `return` its return value. But if you're going to use `.then` etc., don't use an `async` function in the first place. Mixing the two is a recipe for confusing yourself and others reading the code. :-)

Comment: No, you are not correct. At least not in that case. `axios.get` is a complete new promise, which has nothing to do with the promise retuned by `onLogin`. And because in your case you are not returning anything from onLogin it's promise resolves with undefined. And the promise from axios resolves later on, but you don't capture it's result.

Comment: @JoachimBülow - I've updated the answer to perhaps shed more light on why your original wasn't working. FWIW, if you want a deeper understanding of promises, and separately of `async`/`await`, I cover them in depth in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Using await twice and returning the promise including the .then() statement both result in "possible unhandled promise rejection".> The only thing that has worked was de-asyncing the function to only use .then.

Comment: @JoachimBülow - There was a separate place in the original code that wasn't waiting for a different promise (from `asyncStorageHandler.storeObject`). I've updated all three of the above code blocks to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @T.J. Crowder, really appreciated. It all worked out in the end and I learned a bunch. You got an accepted answer:)

Comment: @JoachimBülow - I'm glad that was helpful! That's the main thing. :-)